# Issue with VirtualBox USB passthrough

Tags: virtualbox

I have Backtrack 5 R3 setup as a guest OS in VirtualBox. When i try running my USB wireless card, the Alfa AWUS036NHA with the AR9271 chipset, I see this error.

> ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: Target is unresponsive [ 4.772287] Failed to initialize the device [ 4.774250] ath9k_htc: probe of 1-1:1.0 failed with error -22 [ 4.775452] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc

The wireless card works fine on my Windows 7 Professional host OS.

A quick google search shows that it is a VirtualBox error. See: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9511?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2

Are there any workarounds for this problem? Failing that, does VMWare Workstation have this issue?

Bridged network is not an option here as I need direct access to the wireless card.

Comment: Do you need to have the card directly in the vm, or do you just want the connection?

Comment: @MichaelK I need direct access to the card in the VM, like i said in my last line. I can bridge the connection no problem at all.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but do you have the box-guest-additions installed?
Would an other virtualization software be an alternative?

Comment: Yes and yes, if there is no way round this issue for VirtualBox.

Comment: In that case I recommend trying it with vmware. From my experience with it, USB devices work a lot better with it then with virtual box. It might seem overkill to use a second software, but I think it is better setting up another software and get it done then spending hours on finding a workaround.

Comment: @MichaelK: I agree with you. None of the compatibility problems of VB with USB that I have ever seen on the web had a happy end - the usual solution was to ditch VB.

Comment: The OP link yields an `OperationalError` :p

Comment: @TerryChia What do you mean by "works fine on my Windows 7 Professional host OS"? Is a driver is loaded in Windows 7 for the card? Network cards use custom drivers unlike e.g. keyboards, mice, usb storage which work with generic drivers. So, chances are that the virtualization software cannot multiplex access on the hardware and make it work with both host and guest OS at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer an issue with the newer versions of VirualBox, USB passthrough works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with virtualbox and so just tried vmware. I initially got the same error but after plugging and unplugging a few times it finally got passed through correctly.

Not sure what the actual thing was that triggered it to work but it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Direct access to hardware may be limited or impossible through virtualization.

I highly recommend you run BT on your machine as host, either via installed as a [dedicated partition](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/tutorials/dual-boot-install/), or as a [Live CD / USB](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/tutorials/usb-live-install/) environment.

It can even be used as a [persistent USB](http://www.infosecramblings.com/backtrack/backtrack-4-usbpersistent-changesnessus/).